Python Fatiamento de Strings com índices negativos
Colegas, voltei recentemente a estudar programação, estou relembrando o básico de Python e fiquei preso nessa parte de fatiamento/slicing das strings com índices negativos (não sei se é de fato importante, mas não gosto de passar pelas coisas sem entender rs). Por que a string não está sendo exibida inteira? A última letra está sendo "comida".
Pelo que entendi, em índices positivos, parte da posição 0 até a última posição, como no caso abaixo [0:32], que exibe corretamente. Em relação à posição negativa, não seria o do menor número (no caso -32) até o -1? => [-32:-1]
import os
os.system("cls")

b = "Paul Atreides, duque de Arrakis"

print(len(b))
print(b[0:32])
print(b[:-1])
print(b[-32:-1])



Se quer até o ultimo deixe vazio ([-32:]), -1 como o próprio número sugere, é "-1 do final", que justamente deixa o 's' de fora  - veja https://ideone.com/QEtLYT

Não, o -1 indica que você obtém até antes da última letra. Para obter ató o final da string, basta omitir o valor de parada: b[-32:], pois assim pegará os 32 últimos caracteres da string, que nesse exemplo, é ela inteira.

Complementando, a regra é simples: "start inclusive, end exclusive". Ou seja, o índice inicial é incluso, o final não. Se o início é 0 e o final é 32, quer dizer que vai pegar do 0 até o 31. E como -1 corresponde ao último, se usar esse valor como final, só pega até o penúltimo. ,

O operador de fatia [n:m] (slice notation, slice operator) retorna a parte da sequência do “enésimo” item ao “emésimo” item, incluindo o primeiro, mas excluindo o último.
O segundo índice é a flag de parada.
"Chegou neste índice? Ignore o item e retorne os anteriores."
nome = 'python'
fatia = nome[0:-1]
print(fatia)

Output:
pytho

Se você omitir o primeiro índice (antes dos dois pontos), a fatia começa no início da sequência. Se omitir o segundo índice, a fatia vai ao fim da sequência.
lista = list(nome)
fatia1 = lista[2:]
fatia2 = lista[:-2]
print('Fatia 1:', fatia1)
print('Fatia 2:', fatia2)

Output:
Fatia 1: 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'
Fatia 2: 'p', 'y', 't', 'h'

Relembrando que o primeiro item de uma sequência tem o índice 0.
Se quiser, pode pular alguns caracteres adicionando um passo. Neste caso, mais um índice:
nome = 'eita bixiga!'
# Do início até o nono caractere, pulando de dois em dois
fatia = nome[0:10:2]
print(fatia)

Output:
'et ii'

Veja que o passo 2 pegou o índice 0 mas não o índice 1.
Oia que legal:
reverso = nome[::-1]
print(reverso)

Output:
'nohtyp'

Lembrando que este operador retorna uma "shallow copy" da sequência. Pesquise sobre ela e sobre "deep copy" também.
Link para pesquisa no Google: diferença entre shallow e deep copy

Uma explicação resumida esta disponível lá em baixo na conclusão, mas se quiser mais detalhes continue lendo.
(Para uma resposta um pouco mais didática irei usar uma string um pouco menor.)

"|A-B-C/"

Pelo que entendi a sua duvida é:
"Porque o os dois casos de b[:-1] e b[-32:-1] não são iguais ao caso de b[0:32]?"
explicação
Pra responder isso nos precisamos entender como funciona esse tipo de operação.
Quando você usa [0:32] em b, oque você quer dizer pro python é: "Construa" uma nova string que vai da posição 1 (index 0) ate a posição 31 (index 32).
Veja esse exemplo similar:
my_str = "|A-B-C/" # len(my_str) = 7

print(my_str[0:7])

output:

|A-B-C/

Tudo normal mas perceba que quando você conta a quantidade de caracteres da string my_str começando do 0 (assim como o python "conta") o ultimo termo da string não esta na posição 7 mas sim na posição 6 oque significa que quando se escreve my_str[0:7] o 7 não é a ultima casa da string mas sim a próxima casa na sucessão de  caracteres.
E como essa casa esta vazia o python apenas ignora isso e retorna a string inteira.
Pra testar isso você pode colocar qualquer numero maior que 6 nesse código e perceber que o python sempre entrega uma string inteira.
print(my_str[0:200]) # retorna |A-B-C/
# isso só funciona quando se usa o (:)

De uma forma mais clara quando você digita my_str[a:b] levando em conta que:

a é a posição inicial desejada (contando a partir do 0)

e

b é a posição final desejada (contando a partir do 0)

b precisa ser 1 (uma) unidade maior que a posição desejada. No caso de my_str[0:7] a conta seria 6+1 = 7 (6 é a posição do ultimo caracter que queremos no nosso resultado)
Agora vamos tentar fazer o mesmo na versão negativa.
my_str = "|A-B-C/"

print(my_str[-7:-1])

Primeiro qual é a casa que corresponde a 7ª posição negativa?
E qual a casa que corresponde a 1ª posição negativa?
Pra responder isso veja o seguinte diagrama que representa como o python "vê" uma string (lembre-se esse diagrama só é valido quando se usa o ":" se você tentar colocar um valor maior que o tamanho negativo ou positivo da string sem usar os dois pontos  o codigo retorna um erros de IndexError):

|A-B-C/|A-B-C/  <-string do ponto de vista do python 
^      ^     ^
|      |     |
-7     0     6
^      ^     ^
|------|-----|---index

Agora sabemos que -7 representa o primeiro "|" e -1 representa o primeiro "/" usando esses valores nos temos:
print(my_str[-7:-1]) # |A-B-C

Que nos retornar uma string incompleta.
Para concertar isso basta usar a regra de adicionar uma unidade ao valor da casa que queremos(lembrando, apenas na parte final da string ou seja em my_str[a:b] nos só fazemos isso em b).

O caracter que queremos é o primeiro "/" que esta na casa -1

agora pegamos esse valor (-1)e adicionamos 1 que fica 0
conclusão
Respondendo a sua duvida, não, [-32:-1] não seria uma boa opção para que a sua operação com a string b returne o valor inteiro dela.
Ao invés disso uma boa opção seria [-32:] ou então [-32:0].
E a regra pra usar o slicing de tipos como list e string é que sempre na parte posterior ao ":" para acerta aposição do item que você quer, basta usar a posição normal do item (ao invés de começa do 0 você deve contar a partir do 1 assim como nos contamos coisas normais).

[-32:0] não funciona. Índices maiores ou iguais a zero começam a ser contados do início, então se colocar 0 como valor final, não vai pegar nenhuma caractere, e o resultado será uma string vazia. Veja: https://ideone.com/3qbvMK
